# Issues with InnerHTML tag. Debugger keeps coming back as "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')

Tags: javascript, html

The page I'm designing needs to display a message after the button was clicked. It worked for my classmates just not for lucky me.

The debugger shows the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')`. Following is the code I am running.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function listen() {
    let correct_button = document.querySelector("#correct");
    let incorrect_buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".incorrect");
    let message = document.querySelector("#message");

    correct_button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        correct_button.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        message.innerHTML = "Hello";

    })
    for (let i = 0; i < incorrect_buttons.length; i++) {
        incorrect_buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            incorrect_buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        })
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It sounds like your `querySelector("#message")` isn't finding anything in the DOM and your attempting to set the innerHTML of null result. Write `console.log(message)` after the `let message` statement and see if it found anything. If not, there is no element in your HTML that has an id of "message".

Comment: You could try adding your code to a snippet and will likely get a better response. The snippet is the seventh icon from the left and looks like `<>` with a dark background.